# Send data from html form to Java Applet?

Tags: java, html, applet

I got a problem. I really need your solutions.

Here is the defined problem:

1/ html:

```
<form name="frm" action="">
    <h3>Enter some data:</h3>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txname" value="" size"20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp</td>
        <td><input type="button" name="send" value="Send" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<applet name="myapplet" code="AppletParam.class" width="320" height="120">
    <param name=displayName value="sakura">
</applet>
```

2/ Is it possible to send data from form to applet tag? In my case I need to send from `txname` to applet. For example, `<param name=displayName value="{txname}">`.

*Any ideas? please help*

Answer (score 2):

1. Have the form do a get request for the page with the applet.
2. Parse the the data encoded in the URL.
3. Write the `param` elements for the applet containing the data in the form fields.   Or alternately write the attributes of the deployment toolkit script. This might be done with:-

   - PHP
   - ASP
   - Servlet/JSP
   - Javascript & HTML
   - ..

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

- Create a method in your applet class say: `public void setName(String name)`, do the needy to reflect the new name in applet.
- Secondly in your js write code to get the applet with id, say: `var myApplet = document.getElementById('myAppletId');`
- Later in js itself, invoke it on event say `click` or `submit`,etc whatever suits your scenario, `myApplet.setName('new name here');`

Comment: Excuse me!! Can you help me with simple sample? I seem to be confusing with your step. First `setName(name)` is in java, but `myApplet.setName('newname')` is in javaScript. How can we link those code?

Comment: @sakura, you are getting it right! Just try those steps and let me know.